# Need help in understanding xsl import statement from DITA-OT xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, dita-ot

The statement is as follows:

```
<xsl:import href="plugin:org.dita.xhtml:xsl/dita2html-base.xsl"/>
```

I am new to XSL. I know the href attribute requires a URI but how does the href value resolve to a URI in the above statement. This code is part of the xhtml plugin's xsl in the DITA-OT. There are multiple statements like these. Are these relative paths from a root directory ? How does the DITA-OT code resolve these paths ?

Comment: I assume that `plugin:` is a custom URI scheme known and supported by the software you use, it will have some implementation of a URI resolver that knows how to treat those URIs with the scheme `plugin:`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen You mean something like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864564/xslcompiledtransform-and-custom-xmlurlresolver-an-entry-with-the-same-key-alre) ?

Comment: That link is about .NET while I understand that the Dita toolkit is Java based. I am not familiar with details of the toolkit, maybe someone else can tell you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the root installation folder of your DITA-OT, you will find a file named *catalog-dita.xml*. This an [XML catalog](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/14809/xml-catalogs.html) aimed to provide resolution schemes for XML entities. Excerpt from the abstract of the XML catalogs specification:

> this OASIS Standard defines an entity catalog that maps both external identifiers and arbitrary URI references to URI references.

Open the *catalog-dita.xml* file, and search `plugin:org.dita.xhtml`. You will find this entry:

```
<rewriteURI uriStartString='plugin:org.dita.xhtml:' rewritePrefix='plugins/org.dita.xhtml/'/>
```

Thus any `<xsl:import href="...">` (and also the `<xsl:include href="...">` and `document()` function) with a reference uri that starts with `plugin:org.dita.xhtml:` will be "redirected" the folder `plugins/org.dita.xhtml/` so that in your case, the file `plugins/org.dita.xhtml/xsl/dita2html-base.xsl`, relatively to the DITA-OT installation folder, will be searched.

**But how is this catalog used?**

For example in `$DITAOT_DIR$\plugins\org.dita.xhtml\build_general.xml` (it is broadly used in the DITA-OT so might find these instructions in almost all build_xxx.xml files), you'll find something like:

```
<xslt basedir="${dita.temp.dir}" destdir="${output.dir}" includesfile="${dita.temp.dir}${file.separator}${fullditatopicfile}" reloadstylesheet="${dita.xhtml.reloadstylesheet}" classpathref="dost.class.path" extension="${out.ext}" style="${args.xsl}" filenameparameter="FILENAME" filedirparameter="FILEDIR">

  <!-- A huge bunch of parameters comes here ... -->
  <param name="[...]" expression="[...]"></param>

  <xmlcatalog refid="dita.catalog"></xmlcatalog>
</xslt>
```

This is meant to invoke an XSL-T transformation (`<xslt>` here is an [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) task) with the catalog that will provide the appropriate URI mappings for all the resources needed during transformation. Obviously, `dita.catalog` is a reference to a declared catalog elsewhere.

Open the `$DITAOT_DIR$\plugins\org.dita.basebuild_init.xml`, you will find this:

```
<xmlcatalog id="dita.catalog">
  <catalogpath path="${dita.plugin.org.dita.base.dir}/catalog-dita.xml"/>
</xmlcatalog>
```

Which points to the XML catalog that has been opened at the beginning.